# Android Wear notifications always on front

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I have a foreground service with a notification, when updating this notification on a Wear device if the user is on the watch face the notification is always brought to the front, having more than one notification updating then they are constantly fighting for the screen.

Happens on Android Wear OS by Google - Version 1.2; Android OS - Version 8.0.0

On Wear OS - Version 2.12.0; Android OS - Version 7.1.1 is working correctly

I'm updating this notifications using the 
`NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` and not the `NotificationManager.notify()` like the documents say and I'm keeping the NotificationCompat.Builder reference instantiated on the createNotification method and using it on the updateNotification method

Using RemoteViews instead of updating the contentText I have the same result, the only thing that works is using the `.setUsesChronometer(true)`but this uses RemoteViews, so there must be a way to update the notification without making it pop-up

Create notification method:

```
protected void showNotification(String name, String activityId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = activityIntent(activityId);
    notificationIntent.setAction(MAIN_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();

    notificationBuilder = buildBaseNotification(name, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .extend(extender)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .addAction(wearableNotificationPauseAction());

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Update notification method:

```
private void updateNotificationTimer(DataModel data) {
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(data.getSomethingRelevant());

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

[Issue in GIF format](https://media.giphy.com/media/18496tA31oOguaZAYn/giphy.gif)